# module 'h5py' has no attribute 'string_dtype'

Tags: python, string, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to save a string in python 3.7. In the h5py documentation page it is all about data types such as this one:

```
dt = h5py.string_dtype(encoding='ascii')
```

But, when I try it, I get the following error.

```
module 'h5py' has no attribute 'string_dtype'
```

What is the easiest way to save strings into hdf5 format.

Thank you

Comment: please, edit your post and add full traceback you get. By any chance is your script named `h5py.py`?

Comment: Which `h5py` documentation page?

Comment: @hpaulj, http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/strings.html#variable-length-ascii

Comment: Best I can tell from the `github` code, this was just added in version 2.10.  My installed version is 2.7.1

Comment: I just updated my `h5py` version to `2.10`.  The method is there.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj. Yes, it is only in the newest version.

Comment: I have the problem described at the top, and I'm seemingly unable to update h5py beyond version 2.9.0 using conda.  Any suggestions for how to get 2.10?

Comment: @Grant Petty. Try the following configuration python 3.7.3, tensorflow 2.0.0, keras 2.3.1, h5py 2.10.0, I am no expert but worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Try `conda update -c conda-forge h5py`

Comment: Worked for me. However H5py refused to upgrade from 2.9.0 to 2.10.0 because of compatibility issue. 
The following configuration worked for me -
python 3.7.3
tensorflow 2.0.0
keras 2.3.1
h5py 2.10.0